# How to generate Password Protected output file in Pentaho Data Integration?

Tags: pentaho, pgp, pentaho-spoon, openpgp, pentaho-data-integration

Stuck in a strange problem. As per client requirement, I need to generate all text output files in PDI with password-protection.
I have implemented PGP encryption and Symmetric cryptography(OpenPGP configured on mysystem). But I am at loss how to generate password protected file.

Any suggestions!!!

Comment: Have you tried the `Encrypt files with PGP` step? It's at the job level, so you'd write the text file first with a transformation, then do the encryption in the job afterwards.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your time. Yes Encryption I have achieved. But requirement is to generate a password protected file. Password may not be dynamic rather it could be static too.

Comment: What kind of file do you need to output?

Comment: It can be .CSV or .TXT or .PDF file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to create password protected files using PDI. I would rather suggest you to try the following:

1. Output your files in the one folder.
2. Make that folder password protected. You said you are fine with one password for all files.
3. How to make the folder password protected?

   For Windows:

   ```
    a. You can do it manually. OR

    b. Write a batch script to make it password protected. After you output all 
       your files in that folder, create another transformation to run that 
       batch file which will make that folder password protected.
   ```

   For Linux, try this:
   https://superuser.com/questions/249497/how-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory-in-linux

It is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF, there are configuration settings for passwords in the report designer.

For Excel, there is no way to do that as Microsoft never published a specification for that fileformat. CSV files and TXT files are text files - there is no way you can ask for passwords on text files.